# How to modify object in Python's Rtree index

Tags: python, geospatial, r-tree

I've been using a package called [Rtree](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Rtree/) version 0.8.2 which lets you put geospatial objects into an index and perform searches very quickly.
However, I have faced a problem trying to modify already created index.

So there is an *insert* method that allows you to add object into index:

```
from rtree import index
idx = index.Index()
idx.insert(1, (left, bottom, right, top), 
           obj = {'field1': 'value1', 'field2': 'value2'})
```

And also there is a *delete* method that allows you to delete unnecessary object from index:

```
idx.delete(1, (left, bottom, right, top))
```

Unfortunately, in the package's manual I couldn't find any information about how to modify existing object which is already in the index.

I am particularly curious how to add another field into an *obj* property, which is represented as a dict (like 'field3': 'value3').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to

1. delete the old object
2. insert the new object

There is nothing wrong with doing this; it may help improve the tree structure.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's what I did at the end. It's not convenient at all, but doesn't seem like there is another option.

Comment: Why fo you think this is bad? The better R*-trees do even automatically remove and reinsert points, in order to improve the tree structure.